# PHP, Javascript, Ajax and the aspect of getting a result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file with a lot of checkboxes on the left hand side. I extract the values via javscript and pass them into an array. Which works just fine. I would like to pass then this array via Ajax to PHP in order to mess around with the values and create SQL-statements out of them.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#getSelectedValues').click(function() {          
        var chkBoxArray = [];
        $('.graphselectors:checked').each(function() {
            chkBoxArray.push($(this).val());
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(i + " = " + chkBoxArray[i]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php', // (1)
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json', 
            data: chkBoxArray, //(2)
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data.length);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

Several questions:
(1) what file name do I need to add here? The origion or the target?
(2) I have numerous ways of this: serialization, with these brackets {}, and so on. How to get it done right?

An error that I get is the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: data in graph.php

That makes me wondering a bit, because it clearly shows no data is being send.

var_dumps on $_POST and $_SERVER offer these results:

> array(0) { }
>
> array(0) { }

which is somewhat unsatisfying.

Where am I doing things wrong? The only puzzling aspect is the ajax, all other stuff is not much of an issue.

The site is supposed to work in the following way:
Page -> Checkbox(clicked) -> Button -> result (ajax) -> PHP fetches result -> SQL DB -> PHP gets DB result -> fetch result (ajax) -> jslibrary uses result for something.

Answer (score 3):

1- You need to point your ajax to the script that will use the data you are sending. I would not recommend to point to `index.php`, since you'll need to add a if statement checking if there is data on `$_POST` that is exactly what your're expecting, otherwise it will return the same page that you're in (considering that you are in `index.php` and is making a request to `index.php`). A point to consider. Since it is a whole request and it's *not a method call* to actually return something to your page you need to `echo` things. That said, consider also to set `header('Content-Type: application/json')` then, since you're expecting `dataType: 'json'`, `echo json_encode($objectorarray);`

2- Since you're sending a Javascript array to PHP, it can't interpret correctly the structure, that is why you should use `JSON.stringify(chkBoxArray)` before sending it. But just setting it on `data` attribute would send the number of checkboxes you selected as values to `POST`, so consider to `data: {myCheckboxValues: JSON.stringify(chkBoxArray)}`

In your PHP script, considering all the security measures to take, you can `$foo = json_decode($_POST['myCheckboxValues']);`

Comment: This worked for me. I have added your suggestion in respect to the data field and it works now. Thanks ...

Comment: Check this comment as answer and help the others to see what is correct then. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course you need to pass the target page as url in your ajax call. It can't guess which file should process the data.
As for the `data` property. You need to give your data a name.

```
data: {
    something: "something"
}
```

Becomes: `$_POST['something']`. (value: something)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'target.php', // (1)
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json', 
    data: { data: chkBoxArray }, //(2) Now $_POST['data'] will work
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.length);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```